# How to get table field into grid?

Tags: axapta

I have created **tableA** with fields `itemid`, `name`, `qty`.

I have created one button. In that button I created one clicked method in which I have written a query for selecting `itemid`.

My question is how to assign selected `itemid` into grid?

Comment: Could you be be more specific about how your button selects the item id?
What do mean by "assign" in this context?
Grid values are selected by the datasource methods (`init` and `executeQuery), they are not assigned,

Show your code.

Comment: void clicked()
{
    InventTransOrigin  inventTransOrigin1;
    InventTrans        inventTrans1;
    InventTable inventtable1;

     while select * from inventTransOrigin1
        where inventTransOrigin1.ItemId==StringEditItemNumber.text() &&
        inventTransOrigin1.ReferenceCategory==InventTransType::Sales
   {
        
      


        info(strFmt("%1, %2  ",enum2str(inventTransOrigin1.ReferenceCategory), inventTransOrigin1.ReferenceId));
      
    }

Comment: void clicked() { InventTransOrigin inventTransOrigin1; InventTrans inventTrans1; InventTable inventtable1; while select * from inventTransOrigin1 where inventTransOrigin1.ItemId==StringEditItemNumber.text() && inventTransOrigin1.ReferenceCategory==InventTransType::Sales { plinfo(strFmt("%1, %2 ",enum2str(inventTransOrigin1.ReferenceCategory), inventTransOrigin1.ReferenceId)); }         please go through the code my problem is instead of printing Reference category and ReferenceId ,i want to place in Grid

Comment: Please place your code in the question and properly formatted.

Comment: What datasource do you have in your grid?

Comment: Mr.jan B.Kjeldsen   i created one clicked method in that i select all table fields like select * from custtable where custid==10001 my question is how to assign that selected values from custtable into grid.

Comment: Your question does not make any sense, as selected values are not *assigned* into a grid. They are *selected* and *displayed* by the methods described in my answer. If you want `CustTable` data, then add that as a data source, then do the selection as specified in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

By deciphering you code I conclude you want to select records based on an unbound field.
I would recommend you use two data sources in your form:

1. InventTrans
2. InventTransOriging, `InnerJoin` or `ExistsJoin` to InventTrans

In the `modified` method of your item number (or in the `clicked` method of your button) call `executeQuery`:

```
public boolean modified()
{
    boolean ret = super();
    inventTrans_ds.executeQuery();
    return ret;
}
```

In the `init` method apply the static range:

```
public void init()
{
    super();
    this.queryBuildDataSource().addRange(fieldNum(InventTransOrigin,ReferenceCategory)).value(queryValue(InventTransType::Sales));
}
```

In the `executeQuery` method apply the variable range:

```
public void executeQuery()
{
    SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(this.queryBuildDataSource(), fieldNum(inventTrans,ItemId)).value(StringEditItemNumber.text());
    super();
}
```

This will give the inventory transactions for sales orders to the entered item.

You can avoid all code if you can use the standard search methods of AX. For example use Ctrl-G to open the search line in the grid.

Comment: Mr. jan B.Kjeldsen  canu you please explain in detail,because i am getting error in init()method.Error is=The classform does not contain this method

Comment: If you use AX 2009 or lower then use `this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(InventTransOrigin))` instead of `this.queryBuildDataSource()`

Comment: This is different Question ==>  I had two forms name A and B  in that form A i had one button,my question is when i pressed that button in A the form B has to display.how to do please suggest